# RSelenium still running?

Tags: r, rselenium

Hi used RSelenium for some web-scraping a couple of weeks back. I finished the task but every time I open my RStudio I get this error in my console

```
Warning: namespace ‘RSelenium’ is not available and has been replaced
by .GlobalEnv when processing object ‘remDr’
[Workspace loaded from ~/.RData]

Loading required package: RSelenium
Error in .requirePackage(package) : 
  unable to find required package ‘RSelenium’
In addition: Warning message:
In library(package, lib.loc = lib.loc, character.only = TRUE, logical.return = TRUE,  :
  there is no package called ‘RSelenium’
Loading required package: RSelenium
Error in .requirePackage(package) : 
  unable to find required package ‘RSelenium’
In addition: Warning message:
In library(package, lib.loc = lib.loc, character.only = TRUE, logical.return = TRUE,  :
  there is no package called ‘RSelenium’
```

Along with this the url I used in scraping is automatically loaded in the environment as a variable, e.g.,

```
url <- "www.stackoverflow.com"
```

How can I avoid this because I have to clean the environment everytime I open RStudio.

Thanks!

I have deleted RStudio and re-installed but the problem persists. I am expecting a clean start every time I open RStudio

Comment: It says "Workspace loaded from ~/.RData". If you don't want to reload that workspace, you should delete the "~/.RData" file. (or at least rename it if you do want to keep it around. Since that file is in your home directory, it doesn't get destroyed when you delete/reinstall R.

Comment: I don't have any file named "~/.RData" on my system.

Comment: What OS are you on? `~/` is an alias for your home directory. And file names that start with `.` are usually hidden by default. So the file is probably there. I really doubt R would be lying. You can try running `unlink("~/.RData")` inside of R to delete it.

Comment: I am on macOS Big Sur...Thank you for the explanation and quick solution. It worked! As you said the file was probably hidden, but ```unlink("~/.RData")``` worked.